# Angular 8 Select with [(ngModel)] sets the value but the text doesn't display in the option

Tags: angular, angular8

in short, i have an interface for a client:

```
ClientInterface{
    id:number;
    displayName: string;
}
```

Then in a component i have an array of clients, and a single selected client:

```
public clients: ClientInterface[];
public selectedClient: ClientInterface = null;
```

During ngOnInit data is pulled from an api call to PHP via a resolver which returns the selectedClient object that matches the interface, then assigns it to the selectedClient:

```
ngOnInit() {

    // data is taken from the resolver here

    // and assigned here
    this.selectedClient = <ClientInterface>data.selectedClient;
  }
```

The view has a dropdown:

```
<select name="client" id="client" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedClient">
                        <option *ngFor="let client of clients" [ngValue]="client">{{ client.displayName }}</option>
                    </select>
```

It doesn't seem to be selecting the option?? It works the other way though, if i select an option from the drop down, this.selectedClient has the correct client in the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Angular](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#customizing-option-selection) uses object identity by default to select options but in some scenarios there can be discrepancies when object values remains same but object identity is changed. To handle such scenarios, angular provides compareWith input

> compareWith takes a function which has two arguments: option1 and
>   option2. If compareWith is given, Angular selects option by the return
>   value of the function.

**Try this:**

**component.html**

```
<select  [compareWith]="compareFn" name="client" id="client" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedClient">
          <option *ngFor="let client of clients" [ngValue]="client">{{ client.displayName }}</option>
  </select>
```

**component.ts**

```
compareFn(c1: any, c2: any): boolean {
    return c1 && c2 ? c1.selectedClient === c2.selectedClient : c1 === c2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked, although i'm not 100% sure what the c1: any and c2: any represent here as they seem to have the selectedClient property on them...

Comment: compareWith input accepts function which will be exucted internally by angular with current client object which we are looping in the option element.